# github how to include files from master in new git branch gh-pages

Tags: git, github

github has this feature where you can publish "Project Pages" if you create a new branch gh-pages in your project. For full description see http://pages.github.com/

My project is just html/images, so I just want to serve the master branch.

so how do I create a new branch called gh-pages that is just exact copy of master?
some kind of link operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

You want branch 'gh-pages' *in your GitHub repository* to be the same as 'master' branch.  The simplest solution would be to configure git to push branch 'master' to 'gh-pages' automatically.

Assuming that your GitHub repository you push into is configured as 'origin' remote, you can somply do:

```
$ git config --add remote.origin.push +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
```

Or if you prefer you can simply edit `.git/config` file directly.

Then when you do `git push` or `git push origin` you would push 'master' branch in your repository into 'gh-pages' branch into repository on GitHub.

See [git-push manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for documentation and description of refspec format.

Comment: You meant 'gh-pages' I presume not 'hg_pages'

Comment: I find this works perfectly for the `git push` command, but I haven't been able to get it to work with any of the GitHub for Mac actions (Commit, Commit & Sync, Sync, or even `Push` from the Repository menu). Is there a comparable `git config` line for the `git pull --rebase` command that the GitHub app does (according to http://mac.github.com/help.html).

Comment: @JamesChevalier: It should work for any push, be it from command line or from GUI.  It doesn't affect *pull* at all, though.

Comment: But this way only the branch `origin/gh-pages` will be pushed while `origin/master` remains the same, I have to add `[...] +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` too to the configuration. Am I wrong?

Comment: @cYrus: This way master will be pushed into gh-pages

Answer (score 2):

That's actually the default behavior of the `git branch` command.  The more complicated `symbolic-ref` and `clean` commands you see listed in the "pages" writeup are needed to avoid doing exactly this.

So, at your project root, on the master branch:

```
git branch gh-pages
git checkout gh-pages
```

Or just:

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
```

Comment: so if i update master,  gh-pages will reflect the updates? and if i add some files to gh-pages, will it still get updates from master?

Comment: Not automatically, no; you'll have to use `git merge` to move changes and files from branch to branch.

See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html#_managing_branches for a good explanation of how branches are used.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local clone of your repository, create a new local branch called `gh-pages`, then push that new local branch to your repository, on the branch `gh-pages`

```
git clone git@github.com:<username>/<project>.git
cd <project>
git checkout -b gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages
```