# Github: Mirroring gh-pages to master

Tags: git, github, github-pages, git-tower

I'm developing a jQuery plugin that's being hosting on GitHub. It has a demo included of which I'm manually copying and pushing to the branch `gh-pages`, what I'd like to do is have it so when I push a change to `master` it is automatically pushed to `gh-pages`, or at least a setup where they are mirrored.

I've already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705224/github-how-to-include-files-from-master-in-new-git-branch-gh-pages/1708339#1708339) but not sure if it really answers my question with regard to these requirements:

1. I use [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/), I don't mind using the terminal (Mac) to make changes to config, so long as the solution works with this GUI.
2. I only want this 'mirroring' on certain repos, not on all of them on my machine.

Cheers

Comment: Github now allows pages to be driven from the master branch or `/docs` within the master branch. https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git push origin gh-pages
```

Comment: Cheers Steve, I'll give that a go later and tell you how I get on.

Comment: Nice one Steve, the original solution didn't work but this works a treat.

Comment: @Visgean Skeloru, so every time I push to the master, I then have to do this for gh-pages so master and gh-pages will be mirred.

Comment: @HattrickNZ: yes but look at christianvuerings solution, that one is permanent and automatic...

Comment: [GitHub now allows pages to be published from any branch and directory you want.](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

Answer (score 108):

Add the following 2 lines to the `[remote "origin"]` section of `.git/config`:

```
push = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
push = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

Every time you `push` it will automatically push master to gh-pages as well.
I'm using this for the [jQuery Lifestream project](http://github.com/christianv/jquery-lifestream).

Comment: @James You're welcome, took a while before I found this one as well.

Comment: Does everyone have to do this for each local repo? Or does this happy automatically when you clone it? (after you've committed with this change) Can you commit changes to `.git/config`?

Comment: This is cool, except that this change doesn't get checked into the project, so everybody has the make the change by hand on their local boxes. It would be easy for it to get lost.

Comment: Is there a typical way to share things like `.git/config` changes ?

Comment: @b.long More and more people are using Dotfiles nowadays. http://dotfiles.github.com/ These contain useful shell scripts and good defaults

Comment: What that does is to push the same files onto the two branches, is that correct? Does that build the HTML from markdown, or just mirrors the changes in the master branch?

Comment: This created a `forces` branch and pushed just to that branch when I tried this while using SourceTree, haha...

Comment: I tried this using github for windows (GUI client) and it doesn't work properly. It only commits to the first branch listed under push, and if the gh-pages is first then it auto updates the to merge from the gh-pages branch. I tried using SourceTree and it only commits to the first branch but it doesn't screw with the config file. Why doesn't this work with GUI clients? I don't want to have to open a command line to push and re-enter my credentials.

Comment: Thoughts on @MCSDWVL's answer/comment below?

Comment: Just confirming what Sevin7 said. This doesn't work properly with the Github GUI on mac either. It updates the gh-pages branch, but the master is unaffected. Too bad, this wouldn't been nice!

Comment: [GitHub now allows pages to be published from any branch and directory you want.](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

Answer (score 28):

**Do not do what denbuzze suggests above**!!  The + (plus sign) in the push makes it quietly accept non-fastforward updates.  I found out the hard way that this can irrevocably cause work to be lost by leading to dangling commits.  Simply removing the plus signs makes this a safer approach.

```
push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

now instead of causing a force update this will cause a warning & pull suggestion

```
To https://github.com/someuser/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> gh-pages (fetch first)
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/someuser/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: @denbuzze, is this true!  Have you lied to us! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if what denbuzze suggests breaks anything because I didn't test it, but I do know that what you suggested works.

Comment: @MCSDWVL: why didn't you leave a comment on denbuzze's answer?

Comment: [GitHub now allows pages to be published from any branch and directory you want.](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

Comment: my config origin section has :
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@something:user/repo.git
as it is using * , do I still need to add both lines. I need my one branch to be synced with master.

Answer (score 9):

I'm adding further explanation to [@denbuzze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7472481/3324188) and [@MCSDWVL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943952/3324188) answers.

If you want to push both to `master` and `gh-pages` automatically each time you run `git push origin`, you probably want to add a Refspec to the git config of your repo.

So, according to the [git-scm book](http://git-scm.com), you can add two  [RefSpecs](http://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#Pushing-Refspecs), by adding two `push` values to the repo config file `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/<github_user>/<repo_name>
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
      push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
      push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
```

That will cause a `git push origin` to:

1. Push the local `master` branch to the remote `master` branch
2. Push the local `master` branch to the remote `gh-pages` branch

by default.

**Note**: using a `+` before the spec causes to force push to the repo. Use it with caution:

> The format of the refspec is an optional `+`, followed by `<src>:<dst>`, where `<src>` is the pattern for references on the remote side and `<dst>` is where those references will be written locally. **The `+` tells Git to update the reference even if it isn’t a fast-forward.**

Comment: Will that push all the files from master into `gh-pages`, even those that have nothing to do with `gh-pages`? Why does GitHub make this so complicated? Wouldn't it be far simpler if it just rendered a folder `gh-pages`? Here's an attempt to create that kind of [gh-pages folder setup](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/825950).

Comment: [GitHub now allows pages to be published from any branch and directory you want.](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

Comment: I have additionally in config :
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
Do I still need to add first line to push to master in Origin section ?

Answer (score 3):

I personally like to wrap this in an alias:

```
alias gpogh="git checkout gh-pages && git merge master && git push origin gh-pages && git checkout -"
```

This mirrors your master to `gh-pages`, pushes to github, then switches back the previous branch you were working on.

Answer (score 2):

**commit** and **push** to master..

then :

```
git checkout gh-pages  // -> go to gh-pages branch
git rebase master // bring gh-pages up to date with master
git push origin gh-pages // commit the changes
git checkout master // return to the master branch
```

Answer (score 2):

OR you can just use the cmd below, this will push your local master branch to gh-pages master branch. 
`git push -f origin master:gh-pages`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: [GitHub now allows pages to be published from any branch and directory you want.](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)

---

It was much easier for me to use the `gh-pages` branch as master. There's nothing magical about "master"; it's just another branch name. There *is* something magical about gh-pages, because that's where GitHub is looking for index.html to serve your page.

Read more in [my other answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30646245/1269037).

Using `gh-pages` as master is also easier than subtrees, which are easier than mirroring. You could use `git subtree` as described [here](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) or [here](http://stevenclontz.com/blog/2014/05/08/git-subtree-push-for-deployment/): if you have a directory which contains your demo, you can push that directory to the `gh-branch` with one command. Let's say you name the directory `gh-pages` to make things clear. Then after you've committed and pushed your changes to `master`, run this to update gh-pages:

```
git subtree push --prefix gh-pages origin gh-pages
```

The problem is if your files in `gh-pages` refer to files in other directories outside it. Symlinks don't work, so you'll have to *copy* files in the directory that serves as gh-pages.

If you **[use `gh-pages` as master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30646245/1269037)**, this problem won't occur.