# synchronize git branch with master, selectively

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-config, github-pages

I know how to ["synchronize" two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807459/github-mirroring-gh-pages-to-master) (i.e. the gh-pages branch is updated everytime the master is updated).

What I would like is to sinchronize only a certain directory of master to the gh-pages branch. To be clear, that's what I would like to achieve:

### master:

```
+-- some
|
+-- file
|
+-- here
|
+-- dist/
    |
    +-- some_other
    |
    +-- dist_file
```

### gh-pages:

```
+-- some_other
|
+-- dist_file
```

In other words, I'd like to have gh-pages updated as the dist/ directory of master every time master gets pushed.

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Constructing the commit yourself is easy:

```
git commit-tree -p gh-pages -m "" master:dist \
| xargs git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages
```

Automating that is just a matter of taste.  Simplest is to just write a script and run that instead.  Hooks are an inbound thing for vetting what you're doing to your repo; pushing untested repo changes isn't something git's really set up to automate.  As I recall github doesn't do hooks at all, so if you want a receive hook on stuff you push there, just make a proxy repo and have the hook do your synch and forward the push.

Comment: No, you said you already know how to do the automation so I left that out.

Comment: I know that putting

`push = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/gh-pages
push = +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`

in .git/config will synchronize the two branches, I really don't know if it works with your method